# Display v-for items within a single textarea

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

Need to display the looped values within a single textarea.

I'm using Laravel and Vue it displays the values seperately within there own textarea.

```
<textarea>
        <div v-for="(item, index) in form.items" :key="index">
            <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text"
                            class="form-control"
                            v-model="form.items[index].value"
                            :id="'item-' + index">
            </div>
        </div>
</textarea>
```

I expect the output to display the values on a seperate line within the textarea to make the values editable.

Comment: is that any specific reason for using textarea? simply using multile input boxes without text area

Comment: Eventually I would like a WYSIWYG, its going to be user facing its currently pulling say 10 values and I list kindof want to list them out so the user can edit and save them. :)

Comment: try condenteditable div. you cant do this with textarea

Comment: you want a single `textarea` to display multiple values?

Comment: displaying content like this inside textarea is not possible. You can use a div and make it editable

Answer (score 0):

One easy way to accomplish this is by creating a string of all values separated by \n(new line character) and bind it to the textarea input.Hence your values will be rendered as one value per line in a single textarea. If you need the values in array later you can split the string with newline character and store in an array.